# Tomcat Maximum No. of concurrent File Uploads

Tags: tomcat, file-upload, scalability, servlets

I have a Tomcat Server with 250 connection threads. When I simulate concurrent file upload for 30 files (each 100 MB), the CPU and RAM Memory of the server machine goes to peak i.e., 95% usage.

I use following block of code to read the file data from HTTP Post.

```
// request is instance of HTTPServletRequest
int nDataLength = request.getContentLength();

byte dataBytes[] = new byte[nDataLength];

int bytesRead = 0;
int totalBytesRead = 0;
int bytesLimit = 1024;

InputStream in = new InputStream(request.getInputStream());
try
{
    while(totalBytesRead < nDataLength)
    {
        bytesRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead, bytesLimit);
        totalBytesRead  += bytesRead;
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    in.close();
}
```

My doubts are:

- What could be the maximum number of concurrent File Uploads (each 100 MB files) that a Tomcat Server can handle ?
- Is there any optimization required in my code to make use of all 250 connection threads ?
- Introducing `sleep` can cause lengthy uploads. How to write efficient code ?

Thanks in advance.

regards,
Kingsley Reuben J

NOTE: I wont be able to use third party applications to resolve this problem

Comment: It's hard to give a definitive answzer. It depends from many factors: the power de"livered by your machine (CPU, RAM), the load beside this task, what you want to do with the uploaded files (storage or another processing), the available bandwith...

Comment: The server machine doesn't have any other process other than receiving files and storing them. Also, the machine has 8 GB RAM with Dual Core Processor.

Comment: Don't do this by hand, use a proper library like Commons FileUpload (http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/). No bugs, and properly scalable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running out of memory with the original solution, so stacker's suggestion (storing data in file) should work. Uploading files over http to tomcat is just not ideal to do bulk massive uploads.

You could try using a simpler server / more efficient protocol (e.g. ftp) or profile your Application Server & Application to see where your bottleneck is. One of the things that comes to mind is that HTTP uploads have to be MIME-decoded.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the received data to a temporary file (in smaller blocks, say 8KB) since 30 * 100MB = 3GB and probably you machine starts paging out memory. The throughput is limited by you interface adapter.

Comment: After reading the data, I tried storing the chunk data to disk. The RAM usage has reduced considerably. However the CPU usage remain high..

Comment: @Kingsley Reuben follow skaffmans advice and use a scalable library. Or if you want to make your hands dirty profile the process and find out who is the evil doer